# igraph: unexpected behavior in select edge based on source/target in an undirected graph

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I am using igraph in python. I want to find an edge in an undirected graph using source and target vertex. I am using the following code:

```
g = Graph() # or g = Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertices(4)
g.add_edges([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)])
print len(g.es.select(_source=0, _target=1))
print len(g.es.select(_source=1, _target=0))
```

In case of directed graph, it works as I expected and output is 1 and 0.
But in case of undirected graph, I expected that both print statements will return 1, but instead it is same as previous case.

What is the correct way of finding an edge between source and target (that works both for directed and undirected graph)?

Comment: `g.es.select(_source=..., _target=...)` works reliably only on directed graphs (because undirected edges do not have a dedicated "source" and "target" endpoint). This has caused a bit of confusion not only for you but also for others, so I'll probably make this work in the next version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way to get an edge from source and target vertices is to use the `get_eid` method.

`get_eid(v1, v2, directed=True, error=True)`

Directed is ignored for undirected graphs. The error parameter controls whether an exception is raised is the edge does not exists. If `error=False` it returns -1.

```
g = igraph.Graph(directed=False)
g.add_vertices(4)
g.add_edges([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)])
print 'Edge id: {0}'.format(g.get_eid(1,0))
print 'Edge id: {0}'.format(g.get_eid(0,1))
```

Output:

```
Edge id: 0
Edge id: 0
```

The full documentation is here.

Comment: It will raise error if edge does not exist, which can be suppressed by 'error' parameter: http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#get_eid

Comment: @Avinav I have updated the answer to be more precise.